# Underbar nabla symbol doesn't work

Tags: underline

I want to write a symbol like the one shown in the following image

[image]

but I can't make it work. I tried:

```
$$ \underbar{\nabla} $$
```

but it didn't work (I think the reason for this is that the input for the underbar command should be only text.

How can I make this work ?

Comment: Why are you using the text-mode command `\underbar` instead of the math-mode command `\underline`?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that command :D. Now, I know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\underline{\nabla}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the better answer!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\underbar{\hbox{$\nabla$}}$
\end{document}
```

or, alternately,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\setbox0=\hbox{$\nabla$}\underbar{\box0}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Will accept the answer when I can (apparently it needs some time)

Comment: the system forces you to wait to allow time for, hmm, better answers:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Answers, schmansers.

Comment: `\underline` is the primitive (and math mode), `\underbar` is a latex text mode version defined essentially as `\def\hbar#1{\underline{\hbox{#1}}` so nesting that in another  hbox layer and another math group to get back to math mode  is not the most direct route.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My sarchasm was purely in jest. If you post, the answer is almost assuredly better than mine, and always for good reason.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'd posted an answer before the initial comment (likewise only commented as I knew you wouldn't object:-)